# How do I ignore the authenticity token for specific actions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I have a specific action that I don't want to check the authenticity token on, how do I tell Rails to skip checking it?

Answer (score 256):

Rails 5.2+

You can use the same [`skip_before_action`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_forgery_protection) method listed below or a new method `skip_forgery_protection` which is a thin wrapper for `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`

```ruby
skip_forgery_protection
```

Rails 4+:

```ruby
# entire controller
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

# all actions except for :create, :update, :destroy
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, except: [:create, :destroy]

# only specified actions - :create, :update, :destroy
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

[See all options @ api.rubyonrails.org](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-protect_from_forgery)

---

Rails 3 and below:

```ruby
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: for specific controller and specific action, use: skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only=> :my_unprotected_action. I came here to find the answer to: is this a terrible idea? I'm looking to do this because an ajax response eats my session.

Comment: For rails 5.2, use `skip_forgery_protection`. See [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_forgery_protection).

Answer (score 32):

In **Rails4** you use `skip_before_action` with `except` or `only`.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]
  skip_before_action :some_custom_action, except: [:new]

  def new
    # code
  end

  def create
    # code
  end

  protected
  def some_custom_action
    # code
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It helped me create [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66669446/313756) to a similar question. :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is quite specific. Actually I was working no rails API (POST Method) and struggling with the same `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error.

I just added `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in my controller and it got fixed.

I hope this will help you too.

Keep Coding!

[image]