# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is an error, caused by a form in my Rails application:

```
Processing UsersController#update (for **ip** at 2010-07-29 10:52:27) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", "action"=>"update", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"ysiDvO5s7qhJQrnlSR2+f8jF1gxdB7T9I2ydxpRlSSk=", **more parameters**}

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

This happens for every non-`get` request and, as you see, `authenticity_token` is there.

Answer (score -18, accepted):

Problem solved by downgrading to 2.3.5 from 2.3.8. (as well as infamous 'You are being redirected.' issue)

Comment: @Flip perhaps it's an idea to update the accepted answer?

Answer (score 239):

I had the same issue but with pages which were page cached. Pages got buffered with a stale authenticity token and all actions using the methods post/put/delete where recognized as forgery attempts. Error (422 Unprocessable Entity) was returned to the user.

---

###### The solution for **Rails 3**:

Add:

```
 skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

---

###### or as [sagivo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543601/sagiv-ofek) and [barlop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385907/barlop) pointed out in **Rails 4 and 5**:

add

```
 skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

On pages which do caching.

---

###### Note added by [barlop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385907/barlop) about **Rails 5.2**:

It deprecated `skip_before_filter` in favour of `skip_before_action`.
Consider [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177863/how-do-i-ignore-the-authenticity-token-for-specific-actions-in-rails/34431717) or [this official RoR doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html).

> The *_filter family of methods have been removed from the documentation. Their usage is discouraged in favor of the *_action family of methods

---

###### For **Rails 6** (as [collimarco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51387/collimarco) pointed out)

you can use `skip_forgery_protection` and that it is safe to use it for a REST API that doesn't use session data.

---

As [@toobulkeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376201/toobulkeh) commented, this is **not a vulnerability** on `:index`, `:show` actions, but beware using this on `:put`, `:post` actions.

For example:

```
 caches_page :index, :show  
 skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:index, :show]
```

[Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Isn't this a vulnerability?

Comment: although I agree you have sometimes case where this is needed (like maybe once in lifetime) but you need to realize  you are fixing security by disabling security. Not recommended

Comment: hmm I think someone hit -1 on my comment. I would like to hear why, also read my note on "CSRF protection on single page app API
" before answering  http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/44-csrf-protection-on-single-page-app-api

Answer (score 87):

For me the cause of this issue under Rails 4 was a missing,

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Line in my main application layout. I had accidently deleted it when I rewrote my layout.

If this isn't in the main layout you will need it in any page that you want a CSRF token on.

Comment: We are also receiving this error. But it's intermitted. Could this be the reason or would not having this affect every request with an error?

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes, if your template is missing that line you will get the error. So it's possible some of your templates have it and the others do not.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon thanks, I figured out my case is actually caused by users clearing their cookies or having cookies blocked. Learnt loads from this question!

Answer (score 75):

There are several causes for this error, (relating to Rails 4).
1. Check `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` present in page layout

2. check authenticity token is being sent with AJAX calls if using `form_for` helper with `remote: true` option.If not you can include the line `<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>` withing the form block.

3. If request is being sent from cached page, use [fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) to exclude part of page that sends request e.g. `button_to` etc. otherwise token will be stale/invalid.

I would be reluctant to nullify csrf protection...

Comment: csrf_meta_tags should be in <head>? How can I be sure it doesn't conflict with turbolinks?

Answer (score 62):

`ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` can also be caused by a misconfigured reverse proxy. This is the case if in the stack trace, you get a line looking like `Request origin does not match request base_url`.

When using a reverse proxy (such as nginx) as receiver for HTTPS request and transmitting the request unencrypted to the backend (such as the Rails app), the backend (more specifically: Rack) expects some headers with more information about the original client request in order to be able to apply various processing tasks and security measures.

[More details are available on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22965)

---

TL;DR: the solution is to add some headers:

```
upstream myapp {
  server              unix:///path/to/puma.sock;
}

location / {
  proxy_pass        http://myapp;
  proxy_set_header  Host $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on; # Optional
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I had a proxy_set_header Origin http://$http_host and when I switched to HTTPS I couldn't log into my site anymore.  The solution was to use proxy_set_header Origin $scheme://$http_host - this answer helped by reminding me to look for the actual error message in the log.

Comment: This happened to me after I upgraded an app from Rails 5.1 to 5.2.

Comment: I almost spend 8 hours but this solution worked. Was using rails 6.1, "proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on" is important one

Answer (score 45):

Just adding the `authenticity_token` in form fixed it for me.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
```

Comment: Rails supposed to send the token by default . We don't want to specify it explicitly. I feel the token is changed somehow in this situation here.

Comment: However, if you've built your form not using helpers, you should put it manually.

Answer (score 32):

The authenticity token is a random value generated in your view to prove a request is submitted from a form on your site, not somewhere else.  This protects against CSRF attacks:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Check to see who that client/IP is, it looks like they are using your site without loading your views.

If you need to debug further, this question is a good place to start: [Understanding the Rails Authenticity Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token)

Edited to explain:
 It means they are calling the action to process your form submit without ever rendering your form on your website. This could be malicious (say posting spam comments) or it could indicate a customer trying to use your web service API directly. You're the only one who can answer that by the nature of your product and analyzing your requests.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know what authenticity token is. _Check to see who that client/IP is, it looks like they are using your site without loading your views._ Sorry, what "without loading views" means?

Comment: I means that somebody (probably a spammer) could be submitting data to your form without going through your application's user interface. It's possible to do this using a command line program such as curl, for example.

Comment: John has it exactly right.  It means they are calling the action to process your form submit without ever rendering your form on your website.  

This could be malicious (say posting spam comments) or it could indicate a customer trying to use your web service API directly.  

You're the only one who can answer that by the nature of your product and analyzing your requests.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood Winfield's comment. I thought the app wasn't somehow configured to 'load my views' when I use browser.

Comment: I also had another thought, these requests include a token, but it's not valid.  This could be caused by caching the page rendering your form or something else that causes a stale version of the form potentially.

Answer (score 23):

I found a solution.

When you define your own html form you may forget to include an authentication token string needed by the controller for security reasons. But when you use the Rails generator to create forms you get something like following:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/login/signin" method="post">
  <div style="display:none">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" 
      value="x37DrAAwyIIb7s+w2+AdoCR8cAJIpQhIetKRrPgG5VA=">
    .
    .
    .
  </div>
</form>
```

So the solution to the problem is to either manually add the authenticity_token field or use the Rails form helpers rather then removing, downgrading or upgrading the code Rails generates.

Comment: This worked for me with Rails 6.1, I'm now using "form_tag" instead of manually typing "form" HTML tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If you have done a `rake rails:update` or otherwise recently changed your `config/initializers/session_store.rb`, this may be a symptom of old cookies in the browser.  Hopefully this is done in dev/test (it was for me), and you can just clear all browser cookies related to the domain in question.

If this is in production, and you changed `key`, consider changing it back to use the old cookies (<- just speculation).

Comment: Yes! For me, having an empty session_store.rb was causing the error.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue with javascript calls. I fixed that with just requiring jquery_ujs into application.js file.

Comment: Yes correct, I also had this issue and I added jquery_ujs in application js. It worked.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem, but noticed that it was only for requests using http:// and not with https://. The cause was `secure: true` for session_store:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store(
  :cookie_store,
  key: '_foo_session',
  domain: '.example.com',
  secure: true
)
```

Fixed by using HTTPS ~everywhere :)

Comment: I encountered this when using `rails s` (non-SSL) instead of the SSL endpoint I have set up for development. It wasn't until I read your comment that I realized what I was doing. Once I switched back to using SSL, things started working again. Thanks!

Comment: I faced this issue in development. Instead of `secure: true` I wrote `secure: !Rails.env.development?`

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

in

```
\app\assets\javascripts\application.js
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This fixed the issue for me after upgrade to rails 6.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the <%= csrf_meta_tags %> are present and clearing cookies in browser worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For rails 5, it better to add 
`protect_from_forgery prepend: true` than to skip the `verify_authentication_token`

Comment: Why?  Could you add a reference?

Answer (score 1):

Running `rails dev:cache` in my console fixed this for me! (Rails 6)

I think it might be something to do with Turbolinks, but CSRF only seems to work when local caching is *enabled*.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when upgrading from Rails 4.0 to 4.2.

The 4.2 implementation of `verified_request?` looks at `request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']`, whereas the header my 4.0 app had been getting was `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. A quick fix in my ApplicationController was to add the function:

```rb
  def verify_authenticity_token
    request.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] ||= request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN']
    super
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the reason was because I copied and pasted a controller into my app. I needed to change `ApplicationController` to `ApplicationController::Base`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on localhost. I have changed the domain for the app, but in URLs and hosts file there was still the old domain. Updated my browser bookmarks and hosts file to use new domain and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Following Chrome Lighthouse recommendations for a faster application load,  I have asynced my Javascript:

`views/layout/application.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload', async: true %>
```

This broke everything and got that Token error for my remote forms. Removing `async: true` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is much more specific to Ruby on Rails, but hopefully it will help someone.

You need to include the CSRF token with every non-GET request. If you're used to using JQuery, Rails has a helper library called `jquery-ujs` that builds on top of it and adds some hidden functionality. One of the things it does is automatically includes the CSRF token in every `ajax` request. [See here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L72-L76).

If you switch away from it like I did you might find yourself with an error. You can just submit the token manually or use another library to help scrape the token from the DOM. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972411/react-with-rails-5-getting-csrf-error-for-post-with-axios) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

For Development environment, I tried many of these attempts to fix this issue, in Rails 6. None of them helped. So if none of these suggestions worked for you, try below.

The only solution I found was to add a txt file into your /tmp folder.

In your app's root directory, either run:

```
touch tmp/caching-dev.txt
```

Or manually create a file by that name in your /tmp folder. Since this fixed it for me, I assume the root of the issue is a caching conflict.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when carrying out manual tests of the sign up process of my application (signing up/in with multiple users).

A very simple and pragmatic solution may be to do what I did, and use a different browser (or incognito if using chrome).

This was a ***much*** better solution in my case than disabling security features!!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar error in Rails 6. Having tried the solutions above, I did a form review and saw that I had used a `<button>.....</button>` HTML tag in my  form instead of submitting through Rails

```
<%= form.submit %>
```

form helper. Changing to the form helper resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What if this exception happens randomly and only on production app ? Only for login scenario.

> An ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken occurred in
> sessions#create:

Should I suppose that it may be because some users might have /login page cached and is passed stale token ? No users reports about login problem so I suppose after second approach login worked for them. I use Device if that matters.

Answer (score -2):

In rails 5, we need to add 2 lines of code

```
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :exception
```