# Rails 4 CSRF not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf

I'm on Rails

So I was messing around with my cookies and I might have deleted some important ones related to csrf.  Now whenever I submit a form on my app I get: `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`

When I dig around in these requests it looks like [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f4fdd643f9d19fbbeeec3ac77674f791c9beffa/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L242) is why I am getting these errors.

When I actually debug through my request I get different values for `form_authenticity_token` and `request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']` but I have no idea why.

it seems like `request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']` is the one that actually matches the meta tag on my page (and hidden field tag in the form) and its `form_authenticity_token` that is incorrect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try clearing your cookies

Comment: @infused yep definitely did that. Tried it in several browsers too.

Comment: If you cleared your cookies and logged out of your app something else is messed up besides your cookies.

Comment: @infused entirely possible. Thoughts on what that could be?

Comment: @infused i haven't changed anything else on my app since then, I've reverted my git changes, it's still happening.

Comment: Have you tried everything in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364492/actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken ?

Comment: @infused it works if I use `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` however that seems to defeat the purpose. Additionally, This happens for my devise new sessions as well, which I can't skip if I want users to be able to sign in. Weirdly enough it works on production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, weirdly enough, the reason I was seeing this was totally unrelated to anything else I thought I was seeing.

I had added this line to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

`Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = ''`

because on my production app I am using a cdn and its mapped to `http://assets.mydomain.com` and I didn't want it to resolve to `http://assets.mydomain.com/assets/myasset.js`

Unfortunately on production it looks like it was causing this issue, weirdly enough.

Comment: Oh my god, I could kiss you right now... You have no idea how many days of my life I've lost to this bug. I've delved deep into the rails and rack source code, (and learnt a hell of a lot), but I doubt I would have figured that one out on my own.