# Invalid Authenticity Token on Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using `devise` to sign up/in.

**routes**

```
get 'profile' => 'profile#get_profile'
post 'profile' => 'profile#create_profile'
```

and **profile_controller**

```
def get_profile
    render json: {user: current_user}, status: :ok
end

def create_profile
    render json: {user: current_user}, status: :ok
end
```

**GET:** http://localhost:3000/user/profile returns the expected output. However,

**POST** request throws an error saying:

`ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in  User::ProfileController#create_profile`.

Please demystify this behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364492/actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To disable `CSRF protection` you can edit your `ApplicationController`like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  # ...
end
```

or disable the `CSRF protection` for specific controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  # ...
end
```

`:null_session` strategy empties the session instead of raising an exception **which is perfect for an API**. Because the session is empty, you can't use `current_user` method or othes helpers that refer to the `session`.

**IMPORTANT**:

- `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` must be used only in specific
  cases, for example to allow API request (POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE) without html form
- With `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` you must restrict access to your data with an authorization system because every one could do request against your API endpoint
- Don't remove `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` for requests that are done through html form, **is dangerous!** (read here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)

To handle both standard requests (through html form) and API requests generally you have to set up two different controller for the same resource. Example:

#### Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :profiles

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :profiles
    end
  end

end
```

#### ApplicationController

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

#### ProfilesController

*(standard controller for html requests)*

```
# app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  # POST yoursites.com/profiles
  def create
  end
end
```

#### Api::V1::ProfilesController

*(controller for API requests)*

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/profiles_controller.rb
module Api
  module V1
    class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
      # To allow only json request
      protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new {|c| c.request.format.json? }

      # POST yoursites.com/api/v1/profiles
      def create
      end
    end
  end
end
```

refereces:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-protect_from_forgery

Comment: I have disabled CSRF protection for now. When did  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session I was unable get current_user from session.

Comment: @Emmy `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` provides an empty session during every request, or rather, you can't use `current_user` method or helpers that refer to the `session`, because it's empty.
I edited my answer to try to explain better the different cases.

Comment: @Imran as NickGnd has outlined, and which I think needs to be highlighted: YOU NEED TO HAVE an authorisation and authorisation in place to ensure that rogue API post requests cannot do any damage to your app.

Answer (score 5):

Get requests don't have an authenticity token.

You will have to add the request forgery stuff to your forms using this

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

And address via javascript

```
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
```

Comment: I have not created any form yet, I am doing the back end side only rendering the json output in browser.

Comment: I got it whatever you said but is there another way to fix it because I don't have frontend part.

Answer (score -3):

In `ApplicationController` (or another controller your controllers inherit from) there's a line:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Remove it and CSRF checks will be disabled.

Comment: Don't do this. Its there for a reason. You will open the app up to CSRF attacks.

Comment: @gregblass how is the null_session different from removing the protect_from_forgery line altogether?