# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in PostsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

in my rails blog app i get this error message when trying to submit the form for a new post:

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in PostsController#create
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
Extracted source (around line #211):

```
      def handle_unverified_request
        raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
      end
    end
  end
```

this is my posts_controller.rb file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @post=Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save

    redirect_to @post
  end

  def show
    @show=Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title,:body)
    end
end
```

this is my form code:

```
<font color="#BD004B"><h1>New Post<br></h1></font>

<%=form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f|%>
  <p>
  <%=f.label :title%><br>
  <%=f.text_field :title%>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%=f.label :body%><br>
  <%=f.text_area :body%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%=f.submit%>
  </p>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Can you share code of your form ?

Comment: It can be either a missing part of the view or a missing callback method in the controller that skips the authenticity action for post/put/delete requests. So please as @D1ceWard asked please share the view code and I would as to see the `application_controller.rb` code as well.

Comment: @D1ceWard i have posted the form code

Comment: @radoAngelov i have posted the form code

Comment: That's not `form` it's a show page. post the contents of `posts/_form`

Comment: But you need a "Submit" form that creates a new Post. Shared view code doesn't bring value to the question :(

Comment: @radoAngelov sorry i pasted the wrong file without thinking, added the form code now

Comment: Check if you have `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in your main application layout. If this isn't in the main layout you will need it in any page that you want a CSRF token on like the POST form.

Comment: i have that in my `application.html.erb` file

Comment: Ok, try adding `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` to your `application_controller.rb` file.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364492/actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken?rq=1

Comment: @ldeld what section of the post?

Comment: @radoAngelov that stopped the error but now i get another one: `undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass` from my show file, the highlighted line is `<%=@post.title%>`

Comment: @radoAngelov `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` skip the token verification which is an security issue and btw not a solution, we need more information like the whole content of new/_form, routing related to post and rails version because for now everything looks fines

Comment: `undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass` it's because your instance variable in your controller is called `@show` not `@post`

Comment: @D1ceWard what other information do you need

Comment: Just read above, whole content of new/_form, routing related to post and rails version

Comment: `@D1ceWard` should i change `@show` to `@post` or `<%=@post.title%>` to `<%=@show.title%>`

Comment: @radoAngelov `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` are only used for `remote: true` ajax requests. Normally the meta tags are sent via a hidden input. Can you give an example of the params from running `tail -f log/development.log`

Comment: But I would consider if you really should try either creating a separate branch in git or spinning up a new rails app and running the scaffold generator to get a picture of what a rails crud controller should look like. `rails g scaffold post title body:text`

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, skipping `verify_authenticity_token` is not an option and opens big holes in your app's security.

The exception normally turns up in two cases: Your session has ran out, our the form is sent via ajax without the csrf_meta_tags.

The propper solution for the problem is to rescue the exception and reset the user's session like so:

```
rescue_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken do
  logger.info "Compromised session found."
  reset_session
  flash[:error] = "You're session has expired"
  redirect_to root_path # or new_user_session_path
end
```

Comment: i removed it from my `application_controller.rb` file and there is no difference to the functionality of my app so ill leave it out