# Login with devise-jwt authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-jwt

I cannot figure out how to send a post request to login on devise with devise-jwt

I use devise as web authentication, but want to add an endpoint for api authentication

This is my route

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_for :users,
                 path: '',
                 path_names: {
                   sign_in: 'login',
                   sign_out: 'logout'
                 },
                 controllers: {
                   sessions: 'api/v1/sessions'
                 }
    end
  end
```

This is my controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
      respond_to :json

      private

      def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
        render json: resource
      end

      def respond_to_on_destroy
        head :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If I use postman and `post` to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login`

this Body/raw/JSON formatted data `{ "email": "test@app.com", "password": "0123456789" }`

But I get a 422 Unprocessable Entity :/

Does anyone know how we are supposed to format this?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the `authenticity_token`.
Just skip verifying it in your controller

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364673/14359742) for more information.