# 406 Not Acceptable - xhr image upload to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, titanium, appcelerator, xmlhttprequest, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image from iPhone to my working rails application that uses Carrierwave for processing. Do I need to account for the CSRF authenticity token that rails requires?

I have the following in my Titanium app.js file, taken pretty much from their Snapost example code:

```
xhr.open('POST','http://myapp.com/foos/1/bars');
xhr.send({media:originalImage});
```

My rails action is very simple:

```
def create
  @bar = @foo.bars.build(params[:bar])
  @bar.image = params[:file]    
  respond_to do |format|
    if @bar.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@foo, :notice => 'Bar was successfully created.') }
      format.json  { render :json => @bar, :status => :created }
      fotmat.xml { render :xml => @bar, :status => :created }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @bar.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      format.xml { render :xml => @bar.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

From my device, I get the 'xhr.onerror' alert describing a timeout when I attempt an upload. My server log is as follows:

```
Started POST "/foos/1/bars" for ###.###.#.### at 2011-05-01 17:01:33 -0500 

Processing by BarsController#create as MULTIPART_FORM 

Parameters: {"media"=#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xabdd968 @original_filename="285050.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"2
85050.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20110501-32635-olgooh>>, "foo_id"=>"1"} 

^[[1m^[[36mSQL (1.9ms)^[[0m ^[[1mSHOW TABLES^[[0m 

^[[1m^[[35mFoo Load (0.1ms)^[[0m SELECT foos.* FROM foos WHERE foos.id = 1 LIMIT 1 

^[[1m^[[36mSQL (2.6ms)^[[0m ^[[1mBEGIN^[[0m 

^[[1m^[[35mSQL (5.9ms)^[[0m ROLLBACK 

Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 468ms
```

Comment: Sounds like a similar issue with markdown format in format.js - I'd check: [406 error with XHR request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414446/weird-406-not-acceptable-error)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, it is the authenticity token (or lack there of) that is causing the problem.  [How do I ignore the authenticity token for specific actions in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177863/how-do-i-ignore-the-authenticity-token-for-specific-actions-in-rails) has more details on how to have it ignored.  More details at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html

Comment: I removed the authenticity requirement for the create action, and I got a one-off error of 'EOFError (bad content body):'. Since then, I am consistently getting the 406 error again. Thanks to Roman for editing my log. You can now see the ActionDispatch output in my media parameter. Is this potentially the problem?

Comment: How did you remove the authenticity requirement.  With   {skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token} in the controller?

Comment: "protect_from_forgery :except => [:create]" after a before filter

Comment: So with the protect from forgery off, you are still getting 406 errors?  Hmmm.  I'm not sure off the top of my head, I would probably write up a functional or integration test to try and replicate the issues and then open up the debugger and try running it through there.

Comment: OK, so here is a little progress. I made a dumb mistake of using the 'media' param in my xhr.send(). I changed that to 'file' and included a 'name' attribute that my model requires. Now the POST is being successfully committed to my database, but rails is still returning 406 Not Acceptable. I added 'fomat.js' to my action, but that hasn't helped. I might go back to trying json since I recognized the param issue.

Comment: Now back to "EOFError (bad content body):" when using JSON

Comment: Can you replicate the failure in a functional/integration test?  I find that replicating that way makes it easier for me to use the debugger.