# POST request on Rails backend from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails-3, session, backend, authenticity-token

I wanted to perform a POST request to my rails backend from my iPhone app. However, I don't have access to the authenticity token, which prevents me from performing this operation. I was looking through some resources on the internet and I found [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/sujee/iphone-clientserver-app-with-rails-backend-v3).

On page 19, the author says that this problem is solved either by disabling the authenticity token or by using db based sessions.

Following the instructions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588241/rails-sessions-current-practices-especially-for-rails-3) I have already set my rails application to use the db based sessions. But I don't understand how I can bypass the authenticity token with this technique. Can anyone explain that to me?

Thanks

Comment: are you using devise to authenticate ? it is different for different authentication frameworks.

Comment: No actually I was using a custom-made module for that. But I can change to a framework if that helps. Can you post an answer using Devise?

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't understand how I can bypass the authenticity token with this technique. Can anyone explain that to me?

This should answer your question
[How do I ignore the authenticity token for specific actions in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177863/how-do-i-ignore-the-authenticity-token-for-specific-actions-in-rails)